# Liquibase: how to generate a value for a column while parsing

Tags: liquibase

I would like to programmatically generate a value (id) for a column during an insert using a Liquibase changelog (XML).  For example:

```
<changeSet ...>
    <preConditions ...>
        <insert tableName="my_table">
            <column name="my_id" value="<call-code-to-generate-id>" />
            ...
        </insert>
```

I need to do this programmatically because the id needs a character prefix (determined by code) followed by a sequence number (legacy code and lots of other components in the system use it).  The changelog needs to support both Oracle and SQL Server, and sequence numbers are generated differently (the code currently handles this).

I have looked at ChangeLogParser and SqlGenerator but I'm not seeing an easy way to do this.  I was thinking it might be possible to parse the XML looking for 'value='' and replace the value with a generated id, but I'm not sure the effect this would have on Liquibase to determine if the changelog has been updated or not.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so, how to do this?

I'm using Liquibase 3.5.3 and Java 8.

Comment: You could write your own [extension](https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/spaces/CONTRIB/pages/1998880/Change) to handle this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Implementing a Change extension is overkiil for what I need, but I discovered I can subclass an existing Liquibase Change class called InsertDataChange that should allow me to do what I need without rewriting the insert code from scratch.  I will update this question when I have tried it out.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working using a subclass of the Liquibase class **InsertDataChange**.  I put the class in the package **liquibase.sqlgenerator.ext** so that Liquibase automatically registers it.

```
package liquibase.sqlgenerator.ext;

import liquibase.change.ColumnConfig;
import liquibase.change.core.InsertDataChange;
import liquibase.database.Database;
import liquibase.statement.SqlStatement;

public class MyInsertDataChange extends InsertDataChange {

    @Override
    public SqlStatement[] generateStatements(final Database database) {

        for (final ColumnConfig column : getColumns()) {
            final String tableName = getTableName();
            final String name = column.getName();
            final String value = column.getValue();

            if (columnNeedsId(tableName, name, value)) {
                column.setValue(generateId(tableName, name, value));
            }
        }

        return super.generateStatements(database);
    }

    private boolean columnNeedsId(final String tableName, final String name, final String value) {
        // Details omitted
        return true;
    }

    private String generateId(final String tableName, final String name, final String value) {
        // Details omitted
        final String sequenceName = "whatever";
        final long sequenceNumber = 123L;
        return sequenceName + sequenceNumber;
    }
}
```